# Javascript display object property or variable as a string

Tags: javascript

I want to know if it's possible to do something like this:

`var myObject = {
first: "Hello" + otherObject.second() + someVariable;
}`

Then call it and display in html:
`html += myObject.first()` or `myObject.first`

I want it to display all values of "someVariable" and "otherObject.second()". Currently it display something like:

`function () {
 return 2 * 2
}`

but I want it to display "4" as a string/number so the result would be something like "Hello4". I hope you understand my question :) If thats not possible or it's a bad idea overall to do that, then let me know too and I will figure out something else.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you're question but have you tried using the eval function?

Comment: Hey, no I did not try eval function, but i read about it before in lots of comments, and most peoples say that it should not be used. I tested it now and it seems to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people are right - you shouldn't use `eval` function. Especially, if it is possible to solve the problem without it.

In your case, you can replace this variable with a function, and call it when needed:

```
var myObject = {
    first: function() {
        return "Hello" + otherObject.second() + someVariable;
    }
}
```

Now, you can call it as a function:

```
alert(myObject.first());
// or
html += myObject.first();
```

`otherObject.second()` and `someVariable` will be calculated on function call.

Comment: Hey, this is quite an old post, but your answer is correct so let me accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
console.log("foobar", myfn());
```